# understanding the minesweeper programming p.roblem

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to understand the minesweeper problem: 
**Problem statement:**
Have you ever played Minesweeper? This cute little game comes with a certain operating system whose name we can’t remember. The goal of the game is to ﬁnd where all the mines are located within a M ×N ﬁeld. The game shows a number in a square which tells you how many mines there are adjacent to that square. Each square has at most eight adjacent squares. The 4×4 ﬁeld on the left contains two mines, each represented by a “ * ” character. If we represent the same ﬁeld by the hint numbers described above, we end up with the ﬁeld on the right: 
The test case
 
[image: here is the test case]

I am not understanding the problem. just explain me the problem so that I could solve it on my own. PLEASE DO NO EXPLAIN THE SOLUTION.

( I have already seen [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598121/minesweeper-stackoverflowerror) and many others like this but they are  not talking  about the core programming problems , they are game projects. )

Comment: Looks like the problem is to produce the matrix on the right given the input on the left.

Comment: @kennytm yes. I am not getting, for example, how *... has been writtne as *100.

Comment: have you played [minesweeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Minesweeper) before?

Comment: @kennytm no. I have got this problem in programming site.

Comment: Try to play a round of the game and understand the rule. The problem should then be very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is just to count the number of adjacent bombs per each map cell. The game shows only the already dig up cells of coarse.

You simply count the number of mines nearby ...

1. **input `char map[5][5]` sample**

   ```
   .....
   .*...
   ...*.
   .....
   *....
   ```
2. **create a counter `int cnt[5][5]`**

   It should have the same size as input `map`. Init it with `0`

   ```
    map   cnt
   ..... 00000
   .*... 00000
   ...*. 00000
   ..... 00000
   *.... 00000
   ```
3. **loop through whole `map`**

   and if `map[i][j]=='*'` then simply increment all the adjacent counters in `cnt` something like:

   ```cpp
   for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    for (j=0;j<5;j++)
     if (map[i][j]=='*')
       {
       cnt[i-1][j-1]++;
       cnt[i-1][j  ]++;
       cnt[i-1][j+1]++;
       cnt[i  ][j-1]++;
       cnt[i  ][j+1]++;
       cnt[i+1][j-1]++;
       cnt[i+1][j  ]++;
       cnt[i+1][j+1]++;
       }
   ```

   **To avoid access violations** You should add range checks or separate inner and border parts. You can also use array size enlarged by 1 cell from each side and use just internal part.

   Result iterations on each success of the condition:

   ```
    map   cnt
   ..... 11100
   .*... 10100
   ...*. 11100
   ..... 00000
   *.... 00000

   ..... 11100
   .*... 10211
   ...*. 11201
   ..... 00111
   *.... 00000

   ..... 11100
   .*... 10211
   ...*. 11201
   ..... 11111
   *.... 01000
   ```

For more info/ideas take a look at:

- [Mine sweep in Turbo cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45561564/2521214)

Answer (score 1):

In theory minesweeper can be made as grid of objects. When player use any object then (in classical minesweeper) surrounding objects checks **THEIR surrounding objects** and count how many are marked as mine.