# Check for surrounding mines minesweeper pygame?

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, if-statement, pygame

I'm making a pygame minesweeper game. I'm checking the surrounding blocks to determine what number it is (or color for now), but every square in the left column gets chosen as a 0 (gray color) even though it might be a 1, 2 or 3...

Here I am drawing the grid

```
def grid(self):
        for y in range(self.row):
            for x in range(self.column):
                pg.draw.line(win, (230, 230, 230), (x * width/self.column, 0), (x * width/self.column, height))
                pg.draw.line(win, (230, 230, 230), (0, y * height/self.row), (width, y * height/self.row))
                self.squares.append((x * width/self.column, y * height/self.row))

        pg.draw.line(win, (230, 230, 230), (0, height), (width, height))
        pg.draw.line(win, (230, 230, 230), (width, 0), (width, height))
```

Here I'm creating a 2d list that works as a map of the board/grid:

```
  for i in range(0, len(self.squares), self.column):
            self.squaregrid.append(self.squares[i:i + self.column])
```

Here I'm randomly selecting the positions of the mines.

```
 def mine(self):
        for i in range(self.mine_count):
            index = rnd.randint(0, 399)
            if self.squares[index] not in self.mines:  # this causes the number of mines not to match up perfectly with the selected number, but it is necessary  
                self.mines.append(self.squares[index])

        for pos in self.mines:
            pg.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (pos, (20, 20)))
```

Here I'm separating the non-mines from the mines

```
   def nums(self):
        self.mine()

        self.numbers = self.squares
        for x in self.mines:
            self.numbers.remove(x
```

This is the most important part where I'm checking the surrounding squares.

```
for number in self.numbers:
            self.surrounding = []
            for i, row in enumerate(self.squaregrid):
                if number in row:
                    index = self.squaregrid[i].index(number)

                    if i >= 1:
                        for x in self.squaregrid[i - 1][index - 1:index + 2]:
                            if x in self.mines:
                                self.surrounding.append(1)

                    for x in self.squaregrid[i][index - 1:index + 2]:
                        if x in self.mines:
                            self.surrounding.append(1)

                    if i < 19:
                        for x in self.squaregrid[i + 1][index - 1:index + 2]:
                            if x in self.mines:
                                self.surrounding.append(1)
```

Here I'm drawing a different colored squared depending on the surrounding mines. The problem is that every square in the left is being selected a gray square (which is equivalent to a 0)

```
if len(self.surrounding) == 0:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (200, 200, 200), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 1:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (30, 30, 255), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 2:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (0, 153, 0), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 3:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 4:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 120), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 5:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (160, 0, 0), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 6:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (128, 169, 139), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 7:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (100, 0, 0), (number, (15, 15)))
```

This is my entire code

```
import pygame as pg
import random as rnd

pg.init()

height = 600
width = 600
win = pg.display.set_mode((width + 1, height + 1))


class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.row = 20
        self.column = 20

        self.mine_count = 65
        self.mines = []

        self.squares = []
        self.squaregrid = []

        self.numbers = []

        self.surrounding = []

    def grid(self):
        for y in range(self.row):
            for x in range(self.column):
                pg.draw.line(win, (230, 230, 230), (x * width/self.column, 0), (x * width/self.column, height))
                pg.draw.line(win, (230, 230, 230), (0, y * height/self.row), (width, y * height/self.row))
                self.squares.append((x * width/self.column, y * height/self.row))

        self.numbers = self.squares

        pg.draw.line(win, (230, 230, 230), (0, height), (width, height))
        pg.draw.line(win, (230, 230, 230), (width, 0), (width, height))

        for i in range(0, len(self.squares), self.column):
            self.squaregrid.append(self.squares[i:i + self.column])

    def mine(self):
        for i in range(self.mine_count):
            index = rnd.randint(0, 399)
            if self.squares[index] not in self.mines:
                self.mines.append(self.squares[index])

        for pos in self.mines:
            pg.draw.rect(win, (255, 128, 0), (pos, (20, 20)))

    def nums(self):
        self.mine()
        for x in self.mines:
            self.numbers.remove(x)

        for number in self.numbers:
            self.surrounding = []
            for i, row in enumerate(self.squaregrid):
                if number in row:
                    index = self.squaregrid[i].index(number)

                    if i >= 1:
                        for x in self.squaregrid[i - 1][index - 1:index + 2]:
                            if x in self.mines:
                                self.surrounding.append(1)

                    for x in self.squaregrid[i][index - 1:index + 2]:
                        if x in self.mines:
                            self.surrounding.append(1)

                    if i < 19:
                        for x in self.squaregrid[i + 1][index - 1:index + 2]:
                            if x in self.mines:
                                self.surrounding.append(1)

            if len(self.surrounding) == 0:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (200, 200, 200), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 1:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (30, 30, 255), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 2:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (0, 153, 0), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 3:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 4:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 120), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 5:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (160, 0, 0), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 6:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (128, 169, 139), (number, (15, 15)))

            if len(self.surrounding) == 7:
                pg.draw.rect(win, (100, 0, 0), (number, (15, 15)))



    def main(self):
        self.grid()
        self.nums()


board = Board()


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.run = True
        self.pressed = 0

    def draw_grid(self):
        win.fill((30, 30, 30))
        board.main()
        pg.display.flip()

    def draw_game(self):
        win.fill((70, 70, 70))
        pg.display.flip()

    def main(self):
        self.draw_grid()
        while self.run:
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    self.run = False

            if self.pressed > 0:
                self.draw_game()


app = App()
app.main()
```

Comment: take a look at these [understanding the minesweeper programming p.roblem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40070891/2521214) and [Mine sweep in Turbo cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45561564/2521214) for some ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, that if `index` is equal to 0, then `index-1` is -1.

This leads to an unexpected behavior when you try to access `self.squaregrid[i][index-1:index+2]`, because this is the same as `self.squaregrid[i][-1:2]`.

restrict the lower index to 0, to solve the issue. e.g.:

```py
index = self.squaregrid[i].index(number)

index_min = max(0,index - 1)
if i >= 1:
    for x in self.squaregrid[i - 1][index_min:index + 2]:
        if x in self.mines:
            self.surrounding.append(1)

for x in self.squaregrid[i][index_min:index + 2]:
    if x in self.mines:
        self.surrounding.append(1)

if i < 19:
    for x in self.squaregrid[i + 1][index_min:index + 2]:
        if x in self.mines:
            self.surrounding.append(1)
```

But note, this can be simplified:

```py
index = self.squaregrid[i].index(number)

for r in self.squaregrid[max(0,i-1):min(self.row,i+2)]:
    for x in r[max(0,index-1):min(self.column,index+2)]:
        if x in self.mines:
            self.surrounding.append(1)
```